# Use arrayFilters in order to update a property of an object in nested array of objects, with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection  in MongoDb that has  documents "flights" which contain a field array of objects. I want to update one property of one object at a time. In order to do so, I have to use two filters: One in order to select the document that I want to update, and a second one to select the object in the array.

I am using `arrayFilters` with Mongoose as follows:

This is my Flight shema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const flightSchema = new Schema({
    flightName :{ type : String, required :true}, 
    sits : {type : Array, required : true}, //[{n:1, d:f, s:f}]
    origin : {type: String, required : true},
    destination : {type : String, required: true},
    departure : {type : Date, required : true},
    arrival : {type : Date, required : true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Flight', flightSchema)
```

```
// Models/Flight.js
{
    flightName: a164651,
    origin: Monterrey,
    detination: Cancun,
    sits: [{
        sitNumber: 1,
        isAvailable: true,
        isSuspended: false
    }, {
        sitNumber: 2,
        isAvailable: true,
        isSuspended: false
    }]
}
```

Lets imagine that I want to update the property IsSuspended from false to true in the object   with sitNumber : 2.

```
//Controllers dashboard.js

blockSit : async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const flight = req.body.flightName
            
        const sit = req.body.sitToBlock //sit es 2 
            
        const updateSit = await Flight.updateOne(
            { "flightName": flight},

            { "$set" : {"sits.$[si].isSuspended": true} }, 

            { "arrayFilters": [{ "si.sitNumber": sit} ]}
        )
                
        console.log(updateSit) 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

As far as I can see my sintaxis is correct. However I keep receiving the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find path "sits.0.sitNumber" in schema
```

I do not have to use arrayfilters necesarily. I am open to try any other solution that allows me to update a property in a nested array of objects with mongoose.

Comment: What is your Mongoose schema for Flight?

Comment: I edited my question to add my schema.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `sits` field is array of sub-documents but there is not a schema to describe the fields. Try defining the schema.

```
const sitSchema = new Schema({
  sitNumber: Number,
  isAvailable: Boolean,
  isSuspended: Boolean,
  // etc
});

// in the flight schema

  sits: [sitSchema],
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved:

First I needed to use the method findOneandUpdate in Mongoose.
Also, I added to arrayFilters the property new and set it to true.

```
   blockSit : async (req, res) =>{
        try {
            const flight = req.body.flightName
            console.log(flight)
            const sit = req.body.sit
            console.log(sit)
            const updateSit = await Flight.findOneAndUpdate(
                {"flightName" :  flight},
                { "$set" : {"sits.$[si].isSuspended" : true, "sits.$[si].isAvailable": false} }, 
                {"arrayFilters" :[ { "si.sitNumber" :sit} ], new : true}

            )
            
         
                
            res.send(updateSit)

            
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    },
```